# JavaScript Equivalent of Late Static Binding

Tags: javascript

In PHP, I have the following class definitions

```
class my_pet{

    public static $name = "paulie";

    public static function get_name(){
        return static::$name;
    }

}

class my_dog extends my_pet{

    public static $name = "stacey";

}
```

When I echo using

```
echo my_dog::get_name();
```

I'll get "stacey".

If I change

> return static::$name

to

> return self::$name;

the answer turns to "paulie".

In JavaScript, I have the following object constructors

```
function my_pet(){
    this.name = "paulie";
}

my_pet.prototype.get_name = function(){
    return this.name;
}

function my_dog(){
    this.name = "stacey";
}

my_dog.prototype = new my_pet();
my_dog.prototype.constructor = my_dog;

my_pet_instance = new my_dog();
```

When I call my method using

> alert(my_pet_instance.get_name());

I will always get "stacey".

Is there a late static binding equivalent for JavaScript so I can get "paulie" instead of "stacey"?

Comment: what is your question ?  `this` is always _late-bound_ in js. But you've made `my_dog` a contructor, and then wonder about immediate consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the semantics and mechanism are different in JavaScript, you can still access the sub-class value of the `name` property from the prototype object. Try adding this line to the end of your code:

```
my_dog.prototype.name; // returns "paulie"
```

Answer (score 5):

In your JavaScript code, there's nothing static (or even "static-like").

To simulate static variables, you can attach properties directly to constructors:

```
function my_pet(){}
my_pet.name = "paulie";

function my_dog(){}
my_dog.name = "stacey";
```

However, to achieve what you're looking for, you may want to use the prototype chain instead:

```
function my_pet(){}
my_pet.prototype.name = "paulie";

function my_dog(){
    this.name = "stacey";
}
my_dog.prototype = Object.create(my_pet.prototype);

var stacey = new my_dog();

console.log(stacey.name); //stacey
console.log(my_dog.prototype.name); //paulie
delete stacey.name; // no more shadowing
console.log(stacey.name); // paulie
```

Comment: this specific example may not work, as `my_pet.name` will be overridden by the constructor's `name` property. you might want to change that property name to something else..

Comment: It's not overwritten, just shadowed.

Comment: ok, i stand corrected. i have an urge to call you up and get together so you explain me that whole shadowing thing. i'm tired of tutorials..

Comment: @EliranMalka When you ask for `stacey.name`, it will look for an "own" property of the instance first (like `this.name` defined in the constructor). That property is said to be "sadowing" a property of the same name up in the prototype chain (`my_pet.prototype.name`). Now, if the own property is not found in the instance (e.g. after `delete stacey.name`), the prototype chain will be checked, until "paulie" is found at `my_pet.prototype.name`.

Comment: I see: as the constructor is lower in the prototype chain than our own defined property (i.e. `my_pet.name` is actually assigned to the object `prototype`, which is higher), the constructor's `name` is *shadowing* the prototype's `name`. Great, thanks a-lot! I still think we should get together for a beer though :)

Comment: @EliranMalka Forget the first code block in my answer. I'm talking about a different thing there (namely attaching properties to the constructor, not to the prototype, to simulate static properties). What I tried to explain in the previous comment is that `this.name` (which is `stacey.name`) shadows `my_pet.prototype.name`. And, you mean beer as in "free"? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [**Class.js**](https://github.com/tomFlidr/class.js) javascript library.

There are implemented 2 key properties in every dynamic and static `this` context - `this.self` and `this.static`.
It behaves in the same principle like late static binding in PHP. `this.self` and `this.static` contains class (prototype function) definition with build in properties `Name`, `Namespace` and `Fullname`. Read more in project README - Features.

Syntax is possible to customize in any way you are already used to write your classes (7th demo - [Class.js - example to customize syntax](https://tomflidr.github.io/class.js/demos/browsers/07-syntax-customization/index.html)).

It works in all **old browsers** without ES6 support, in **Node**, in **Windows Script Host** environment and also in **Adobe scripts**.

So the code above should looking like:

```
Class.Define('MyPet', {
    Static: {
        GetStaticName: function () {
            return this.static.Name;
        },
        GetSelfName: function () {
            return this.self.Name;
        }
    }
});

Class.Define('MyDog', {
    Extend: MyPet
});

console.log(MyPet.GetSelfName()); // MyPet
console.log(MyDog.GetSelfName()); // MyPet

console.log(MyPet.GetStaticName()); // MyPet
console.log(MyDog.GetStaticName()); // MyDog
```